# Just published app and not link with Google AdMob

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob, ads

I have just published app on AppStore as well as PlayStore. And AdMob will take upto 7 days to listing/displaying App for link. My question is, Is it necessary to link Google AdMob? And What will do If my audience play game without linking the Apps with AdMob? It will affect to earning or chance to block account?

Answer (score 2):

> It will not affect your earnings. You will get proper stats after
>   linking. Linking does not effect earnings. You can do it whenever
>   listing become available for link.

Comment: Thanks for improving knowledge also no worry about  blocking account right? Do you have any link then also put here so I can read further more detais